# installing Django on a remote server not working

Tags: python, linux, django, apache-http-server, mod-wsgi

I am attempting to install Django on a remote server.  I have yum installed the following:

apache
mod_wsgi
Django
mysql
(python is already installed)

I have uploaded my project to the directory:  /home/ec2-user

I am now on the step to point apache to the project and wsgi file.  From the django site it explains that a virtual host entry must be created in the httpd.conf .  I have added the following entry:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ec2-user/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/ec2-user/mysite

<Directory /home/ec2-user/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

When I hit the root of my site,  I get the following error:  You don't have permission to access / on this server.

If I change the user and group in httpd.conf to ec2-user which I believe is the owner of the wsgi file, I get the error:  The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Am I missing a step or have I setup the virtual host incorrectly?

Comment: This is a permissions problem; and possible solutions for it are listed in the [apache wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied). Most probably you have SELinux enabled and you need to run `chcon` to fix it. This is not really programming related though.

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [su]